# C++ cout fresh array gibberish

Tags: c++

When I "cout" an empty array, I get gibberish.  Why?

```
int main() { char test[10]; cout << test; return 0; }
```

...returns some unicode blather.  An easy answer I'm sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't initialize the array you got a garbage value (test[0] is what you are printing out).

Initialize it:

```
int main() { 
    char test[10] = {};
    cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

Just like to note:

Just because some compilers initialize stuff (like some compilers initialize ints, floats etc., at 0) it is not always the case, and you can get a garbage value otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Because your array isn't initialized. Its contents can be anything, and you get undefined behavior using them.

You can initialize them all to zero:

```
char test[10] = {};
```

And when printed, will print nothing.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as an "empty array" in C++. You defined an array of 10 `char`s - you got an array of 10 `char`s. Since it is a local array, by default it is left uninitialized, meaning that each of the 10 `char`s contains garbage. That garbage is what you printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your array isn't initialized to anything and you're outputting the first element of that uninitialized array.

If you want predictable behavior, you need to initialize the array first (the following initializes to an empty array):

```
int main() { char test[10] = {}; cout << test; return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An array without initialization will be filled with whatever occupied the memory before, this is what you're setting in the output. It might also be worth noting you'll likely see differences between debug and release compilations. Many compilers will automatically initialize variables in debug mode, oftens it's a compiler setting. You should not rely on this though. There are a couple of ways you can initialise a character array.

Simply

```
char test[10] = {};
```

With some text

```
char test[] = "some text";
```

As individual characters

```
char test[] = { 's', 'o', 'm', 'e' };
```

The first value set (for strings this is an empty string as '\0' is seen as terminator

```
char test[] = { 0 };
```

Or like this.

```
char test[];
test[0] = '\0';
```

Also remember array and pointer equivalence(s)

Where

```
char* test = "some text";
```

is the same as

```
char test[] = "some text";
```

Comment: `char *test` and `char test[]` are *not* equivalent at all. An array type is converted to a pointer to char type when used in an expression except when it is the operand of `&` or `sizeof`.

Comment: "Also remember array and pointer equivalence(s)" There are no equivalences, they are different types.

Comment: good points and I was not clear - I meant equivalence describing certain properties, not talking about type equivalence. As taught in many C and C++ classes around the world. e.g. eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10e.html. Probably inappropriately named, but widely understood none the less.